# Close window from browser history

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application where I am using JavaScript for the client side scripting. Now my requirement is to close all the opened window which were opened through `window.showModalDialog()`.

For this, I read the history of the browser using `window.history.length`, but I do not know how to close each window. This works well for `window.open()`, but not for `window.showModalDialog()`.

Could you please guide me to move forward?

Comment: Normally only the page that opened the window  (and the window itself) can close it using javascript. You cannot close a window opened vy another page than your.

Comment: Hi Cedric, It works fine if I use window.returnValue on the body's onunload event. but the requirement is to close from history.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the opened window as follows:

**To Open:**

```
var window1=window.open("http://somedomain.com");
var window2=window.open("http://someotherdomain.com");
```

**To Close**

```
window1.close();

window2.close();
```

But be sure you call `window1.close()` and so on.. on the same script where you opened it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `window.showModalDialog`. [Firefox has deprecated it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog), and [Chrome has removed it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345831). Also take a look at [window.showModalDialog: What It is and Why You Should Never Use It](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/).

The idea of `showModalDialog` is that all scripts are paused while the modal window is open. Thus, using `window.close` doesn't work, since as long as the window is open, no more scripts are being executed.

One possibility is to have JavaScript in the modal dialog so that is closes *itself*. You will not be able to close it from outside.